# How to get XML on same page instead of going to the response page of server

Tags: php, xml

The problem is simple but I can't seem to work it out. I am posting http data through from in the following manner:
  
I get a response xml but on a new page. I have read about how to handle the xml response in php (by using $xmlData = simplexml_load_string($dataPOST); but the problem is after submitting the new page opens i.e. the user goes directly to the response page. How to disable this and get the response in php instead of opening it in a new page.

Comment: Post the form to its self, then use curl to make the post request, process the response and display it.

Comment: Could you show the code you're using that's generating the <form> and <submit>/<button> tags so that people can provide more specific advice?

Comment: can't we have anything else beside curl. @CC i am using simple form with some parameters and then posting the data to the api url of site. The api url gives me response but its on a new page.